# How is enemy damage from weapons and super weapons rolled?

Tags: combat, damage, troika

In the Troika! SRD page 67 are the enemies *Troll* and *Ven*. The Troll does damage as *Weapon* and the Ven as *Super Weapon*. But there are no generic damage tables for those.

The *Zoanthrop* for example does damage as a *Modest Beast* which is listed in the table of *Beastly Weapons* on page 70.

How is enemy damage for (Super) Weapon calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research in the chats for Troika! the following answers appear:

1. The Troll's weapon is to be defined by the GM. The text is just not clear about it. The GM would define them like *Troll with Club* or *Troll with Hammer* and the damage is rolled accordingly.
2. Super Weapon damage has been omitted on purpose. Using any weapon with double damage seems to be common approach. Like *Ven with Super Hammer* would roll hammer damage and double it.

Comment: I'm not really sure how "Damage as Weapon" is unclear.